# Bounds for solution of inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If I consider the solution to the PDE $$u_{xx}+\lambda u=1$$ with boundary conditions $u^\prime(0)=u(1)+au^\prime(1)=0$, can I give upper and lower bounds to the solution somehow without knowing the solution a priori?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ positive or negative? Also, what do you mean by an upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{xx}+\lambda u=1$$
HINT :

This is not a PDE because there is only one variable. This is an ODE:
$$u''(x)+\lambda u(x)=1$$
Change of function : $\quad u(x)=v(x)+\frac{1}{\lambda}$
$$v''(x)+\lambda v(x)=0$$
with conditions : $\quad\begin{cases} v'(0)=0\\v(1)+\frac{1}{\lambda}+av'(1)=0\end{cases}$

I suppose that you know how to solve this homogeneous linear ODE.